# Rosetta like localization for ASP.NET MVC web applications?

Tags: .net, python, asp.net-mvc, django

Recently, I used the python django framework and one aspect I liked there a lot is the [django-rosetta](http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/) module that allows you to extract the content of your website and create multi language translations with very a nice web interface.

I was wondering if such thing exists for the ASP.NET framework or for ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

Just use .NET Resources (for mvc, if you want access to your resources inside your controller, don't use App_Globalresources)

Comment: As I understand it what he wants is creating the localized versions from a web-interface, possibly even with the help of his users.

Comment: This is correct, what I was after the experience and ease of creating translations of my website to other languages. I knew about the resources, but it is rather clumsy...